# Error: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, string, window-functions

I have this table `tbl_buku`:

```
id_buku  judul_buku   tahun_buku
1          Bioogi          2010
2          Fisika          2010
3          Informatika     2012
4          Kimia           2012
```

I use query like this, but I am getting an error:

```
select case when t1.tahun_buku=t2.tahun_buku then ''
            else t1.tahun_buku end tahun_buku,t1.judul_buku
from tbl_buku t1 left join tbl_buku t2
on t1.id_buku-1=t2.id_buku;
```

I want to show table like this:

```
tahun_buku     judul_buku
2010             Biologi
                 Fisika
2012             Informatika
                 Kimia
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to use `lag()` window function. Details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Comment: please give me example.

Comment: SQL is the wrong tool for suppressing repeated values in a column. That's what report writers are for. (You have a presentation-level problem, not a database problem.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem in your query is that  `tahun_buku` is of `datatype int` and you are trying to select an empty `string` (`''`).

You have to workarounds:

Change `tahun_buku` to be `varchar` (2010,2012..will be consider as strings I dont know if it is ok)

Set:

```
select case when t1.tahun_buku=t2.tahun_buku then null else t1.tahun_buku end tahun_buku,t1.judul_buku
from tbl_buku t1 left join tbl_buku t2
on t1.id_buku-1=t2.id_buku;
```

Answer (score 3):

- Use the [window function **`lag()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) to get values from the previous row.
- Use `NULL` for "empty" values in a [numeric column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) - like [@apomene already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23912251/939860).
  The empty string `''` can only be used in [character types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) like `text` or `varchar`.
- Use [**`NULLIF()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) in this particular case to substitute the NULL value.

```
SELECT NULLIF(lag(tahun_buku) OVER (ORDER BY tahun_buku, judul_buku)
            , tahun_buku) AS tahun_buku
     , judul_buku
FROM   tbl_buku
ORDER  BY tahun_buku, judul_buku;
```