# Unable to insert numeric values into integer column in postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin

I already referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297980/pg-copy-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911844/error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer/23912251), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513058/postgresql-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-1e06). So, please don't mark as duplicate

I have a raw data in pandas dataframe  which is called `temp_id` as shown below.

The column is of datatype `float64` because of NA's and it looks like as shown below in `jupyter notebook`

```
temp_id
55608.0
55609.0
NaN        
55610.0
NaN        
55611.0
```

In csv file, the same column looks like as shown below

```
temp_id
55608
55609
        #empty row indicating NA        
55610
        #empty row indicating NA
55611
```

Am trying to copy this data into a postgresql table with below table definition. Please note that it is not primary key and can have empty rows

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
  temp_id integer
  
);
```

When I try to copy the data, I get the below error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "55608.0"
CONTEXT:  COPY temp, line 2, column temp_id: "55608.0"
```

How can I avoid this and insert this data into a integer column in Postgresql table? The below are the miscellaneous characters that I give in pgadmin during `import csv`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried casting the column to integer via `.astype(int)` before inserting? The error seems to indicate there's an issue with the decimal point in the floats

Comment: If I try to cast it in `pandas`, it throws error because the column has `na` values. So cannot convert to `int`.

Comment: DataFrame columns can mix types, but the dtype will be read as "object". Replace None values with the string "NULL" which is used in SQL databases in place of NaN. Then, filter for your numerical values and cast them to int using `astype`.

Comment: @LukasThaler - I get this error `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer - but in csv display, it all looks like it's integer already. how come in error message it is showing float value?

Comment: Are you loading the data directly from the csv using Postgres' COPY functionality or from the dataframe through Python? If it's the latter, the dtype and formatting from the df is fed to the database, and that contains the decimal point

Comment: Because either you or another process may be using numpy or pandas. `NaN` is a value in float, but int values do not have `NaN`. Said another way: Trying to build a column with `1, 2, 3.1`, the computer will assume the entire column is a float. Since `NaN` ony exists in floats, then the whole column becomes one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is similar to what @Lukas Thaler posted. But instead of `astype(int)`, I had to use `astype(Int64)`

```
df['temp_id'] = df['temp_id'].astype('Int64')
```

This worked well to convert columns with `NA` to Int64 type and I was able to upload successfully.

So, it's not `int` but `int64`.

Answer (score 1):

The column you are trying to insert contains `NaN` (or `None`). One interesting thing to know is that the floating-point type does have a special value for `NaN` but integers do not. So when reading the csv file, the computer (pandas module) assumes that the whole column is made out of floating-point numbers.

```
a = [1, 2, 3.01] # Will be float when read by Pandas.
b = [1, 2, None] # Will be float when read by Pandas.
```

## Solutions

1. Remove rows with NaN & set to int

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col=[1, 2, 3, 4, None]))
df = df.dropna()
df = df.astype(int)
```

2. Some SQL databases use `"NULL"` to represent `NaN`, but it must be sent as a string. In the database, the column will be of `int`, but it must be set to "nullable".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col=[1, 2, 3, 4, None]))
# Note that Pandas accept mixed type columns. The column dtype will be of "Object".
df = df.fillna('NULL')
df = df.astype(str)
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0', ''))
```